# c# winform I can't access the data I moved in the drag drop event

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, drag-and-drop, listbox

```
 private void lbxMevcutOlmayanUnvanlar_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyState == 1)
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
        }

        private void lbxMevcutOlmayanUnvanlar_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {                MevcutOlmayanUnvanlarDataSource.Rows.Add((DataRow)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataRow)), (DataRow)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataRow)));//I cannot access the data in e.data
        }

        private void lbxMevcutUnvanlar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            int sira = lbxMevcutUnvanlar.IndexFromPoint(point);
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                lbxMevcutUnvanlar.DoDragDrop(lbxMevcutUnvanlar.Items[sira], DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIvoJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF0Vy.png)

The data comes in rows one below the other. actually it should come as columns under the name of "bipkod" and "bipaciklama".

Comment: You have already cast it as a `DataRow` so all you need to do is `MevcutOlmayanUnvanlarDataSource.Rows.Add((DataRow)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataRow)));`

Comment: @Charlieface "System.ArgumentNullException: Argument ''row' cannot be null." it gives error like this

Comment: What is the type of `lbxMevcutUnvanlar.Items[sira]`? Also you should check if `IndexFromPoint` returns a valid item

Comment: @Charlieface data is returning. I've already shown it in pictures.  lbxMevcutUnvanlar.Items[sira] type of ObjectCollection

Comment: Then why are you trying to cast it to a `DataRow`? You will have to transform it somehow.

Comment: @Charlieface because i am trying to add to datatable. so i need to convert it to datarow

Comment: Then casting is the wrong thing. I don't know what your `ObjectCollection` contains so wouldn't know how to convert it. I suggest you give a [mcve]

Comment: Your DataObject contains a `DataRowView`, not a `DataRow`. -- Note that usually you cannot directly add a DataRow that belongs to a DataTable to another DataTable, even if they share the same Schema. If the Schema is exactly the same, you have to use the  `[DataRowView].Row.ItemArray` (i.e., a copy of the Values).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.